# Can't load a csv file using CSVLoader

Tags: java, spring-boot, weka

While using weka csv loader it gives me error in setSource Function " cannot resolve setSource

```
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.CSVLoader;
import java.io.File;
@SpringBootApplication
public class Demo3Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo3Application.class, args);
    }


    // Load CSV file
    CSVLoader loader = new CSVLoader();
    loader.setSource(new File("C:\\Users\\user\\IdeaProjects\\demo3\\testdata3.csv.csv"));
    Instances data = loader.getDataSet();
}
```

Comment: please share the error that you are getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In Java, any task/operation which is to be performed should be inside a function.**

Below is the updated code.

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.CSVLoader;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Demo3Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo3Application.class, args);
        CSVLoader loader = new CSVLoader();
        loader.setSource(new File("C:\\Users\\Caroline.Karam\\IdeaProjects\\demo3\\testdata3.csv.csv"));
        Instances data = loader.getDataSet();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.CSVLoader;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Demo3Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo3Application.class, args);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void loadCSV() {
        try {
            // Load CSV file
            CSVLoader loader = new CSVLoader();
            loader.setSource(new File("C:\\Users\\Caroline.Karam\\IdeaProjects\\demo3\\testdata3.csv.csv"));
            Instances data = loader.getDataSet();
            // TODO: Do something with the data

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Log and handle the exception
            System.err.println("An error occurred while loading the CSV file: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```